# JXBrowser 6.2 and Java swing

Tags: jxbrowser

I'm new using JXBrowser. I'm trying to run GoogleMapsSample on ubuntu 12.04 and NetBeans but the JFrame shows nothing, just the next message: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, and something like: Possible error with Internet access, or DNS server doesn't respons or a firewall does not allow network access to Chromium.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that Chromium cannot file the HTML file you are trying to load. I suppose you use the example from the article [JxBrowser & Google Maps](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012874-google-maps). Please make sure that you provide full path to the **map.html** file. For example:

```
browser.loadURL("C://map.html");
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm using that example. Nevertheless, I made a little bit change:

Comment: JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setSize(900, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Provide the correct full path to the map.html file, e.g. D:\\map.html
        String cadena = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println(cadena);
        browser.loadURL(cadena+"/src/Imagenes/map.html");

Comment: This is the full path for the file: /home/bruno/NetBeansProjects/MapsExample//src/Imagenes

Comment: At the begining, I got the next output in console: 09:29:52 INFO: OS name: Linux
09:29:52 INFO: JRE version: 1.6.0_45 32-bit
09:29:52 INFO: JxBrowser version: 6.2
09:29:52 INFO: The '/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.2/locales' file doesn't exist.
09:29:52 INFO: Extracting Chromium binaries to '/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.2'
09:29:52 INFO: The '/chromium-linux32.zip' JAR resource URL is jar:file:/home/bruno/JXBrowser/jxbrowser-6.2-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux/lib/jxbrowser-linux32-6.2.jar!/chromium-linux32.zip